# problema con login perl

Tags: perl

Tengo el problema con un login que hice usando perl CGI ... resulta que aunque ponga un registro que ya hiciste en la base de datos me devuelve el alert de datos incorrectos.

El código es el siguiente:

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);
use CGI;
use DBI;
use strict;
use CGI::Session;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);


my $cgi = new CGI;
my $email = $cgi->param('email',$cgi->param("email"));
my $pass = $cgi->param('pass',$cgi->param("pass"));
my $pwd = md5($pass);
my $root="root";
my $pass="";
my $host="localhost";
my $db="amaclone";
my $sql=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db;host=$host",$root,$pass);



my $consulta = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email='$email' And password='pwd'";
my $consulta2 = $sql->prepare($consulta);

my $row = $consulta2->fetchrow_hashref();
my $encontrar = 0;
while ($consulta2->fetch())
{
    $encontrar = 1;
}

if($encontrar eq 1)
{

    my $session=new CGI::Session;
    $session->param('uid', $row->{user_id});
    $session->param('uname', $row->{first_name});

    $session->expire("+1h");
    $session->flush();
    print $session->header(-location => "privado.cgi");
}else{
    print $cgi->header(-type=> 'text/html',
                       -charset=>'utf-8');
    print "<script>alert('Datos incorrectos')</script>";
    print "
    <script>
    exit;
    </script>"
}

$sql->disconnect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Cada vez que realizas un fetch estás extrayendo un registro de tu consulta. Si tu consulta sólo tiene un registro queda vacía luego del primer fetch. Por eso te devuelve "datos incorrectos".

```
my $row = $consulta2->fetchrow_hashref(); # Primer fetch
my $encontrar = 0; 
while ($consulta2->fetch()) # Siguientes fetchs
```

Cambia tu código a

```
my $encontrar = 0; 
while (my $row = $consulta2->fetchrow_hashref()) # Primero y siguientes fetchs
```

Answer (score 0):

El operador de comparación 'eq' es para comparar texto, no números. Si quieres ver si dos números son iguales debes usar el comparador numérico '=='.

Comment: Ya hice la modificación y sigue sin funcionar siempre me dice datos incorrectos aunque el registro exista

Comment: Carlos, quizás este no sea el mejor sitio para responder preguntas de forma escalonada (no se puede poner código en los comentarios de las respuestas). En el foro de "Perl en Español" te recibiremos con los brazos abiertos y podremos darte un mejor servicio.